# SonarLint Javascript custom rules: No Analysers installed: No js file scanned

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I'm trying to create a custom rules bundle for javascript.
I have created custom rules by following same strucuture as defined in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/javascript-custom-rules.

Here in report no js file is scanned and no analyzers installed.
Please point out to me what am I missing

p.s.In pom.xml, sonar-packaging-maven-plugin change  <pluginKey>javascript</pluginKey> and remove   <basePlugin>javascript</basePlugin>.

Copy generated jar to plugins directory in sonarlint commandline tool.
Run sonarlint.bat file.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
INFO: Java 1.7.0_80 (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: Download javascriptcustom-2.1.4.jar
INFO: No analyzers installed
INFO: Index files
INFO: 0 files indexed
INFO:

-------------  SonarLint Report  -------------

  No files analyzed

-------------------------------------------


INFO: SonarLint HTML Report generated: D:\GScanOjetRules\sonarlint-cli1.0\sonarlint-cli-1.0\bin\.sonarlint\sonarlint-report.html
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------------    --
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.991s
INFO: Final Memory: 2M/118M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do your custom rules work when included in a standard analysis?

Comment: You mean custom rules.Junit tests are running fine. https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/javascript-custom-rules/src/test/java/org/sonar/samples/javascript/checks/ForbiddenFunctionUseCheckTest.java

Comment: Hi @Ann, Please find the sample project and sonarlint plugin https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2qeronj307g5pr9/AAAjwiliuxlh2iKWnfMTC_P6a?dl=0

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you're trying to make your JavaScript custom rules plugin working with the SonarLint "Standalone Mode" which is not something that we've tested or thought about. Do you confirm my feeling ?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to build javascript custom rules.Is there any way to make this work in sonar lint "Standalone Mode"